# Pandas: cannot import name adjoin

Tags: python, pandas, pretty-print

From Wes:

```
def side_by_side(*objs, **kwds):
    from pandas.core.common import adjoin
    space = kwds.get('space', 4)
    reprs = [repr(obj).split('\n') for obj in objs]
    print adjoin(space, *reprs)
```

Apply below:

```
  import pandas as pd

  df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))


side_by_side(df1, df2)
```

Throws error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-2674cd8a228c> in <module>()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 side_by_side(df1, df2)

<ipython-input-24-9f441ebc9cb3> in side_by_side(*objs, **kwds)
      1 def side_by_side(*objs, **kwds):
----> 2     from pandas.core.common import adjoin
      3     space = kwds.get('space', 4)
      4     reprs = [repr(obj).split('\n') for obj in objs]
      5     print adjoin(space, *reprs)

ImportError: cannot import name adjoin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this function has been moved to `pandas.formats.printing`:

```
In [69]: from pandas.formats.printing import adjoin
```

**UPDATE**: [as already mentioned by @debo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44786350/5741205) for Pandas 0.20.0+ use:

```
from pandas.io.formats.printing import adjoin
```

Comment: 'import pandas as pd'  fails, Must use 'import pandas'

Answer (score 1):

Changed for pandas version 0.20.*

`from pandas.io.formats.printing import adjoin`