# Print HTML from raw print tables in pandas/ jupyter

Tags: html, pandas

Using the code from:

[Pandas: cannot import name adjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156965/pandas-cannot-import-name-adjoin/44786350#44786350)

I get print out below. Can I change the output into a an HTML layout easily.

```
def side_by_side(*objs, **kwds):
    from pandas.io.formats.printing import adjoin, pprint_thing
    space = kwds.get('space', 6)
    reprs = [repr(obj).split('\n') for obj in objs]
    print adjoin(space, *reprs) 



import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))        
side_by_side(df1, df2)

          0         1         2                0         1         2
0  0.786732  0.688221  0.339926      0  0.624153  0.611812  0.933379
1  0.444541  0.366336  0.840466      1  0.734519  0.824821  0.335849
2  0.328322  0.322575  0.935291      2  0.907465  0.185209  0.407982
3  0.919987  0.968674  0.807549      3  0.737452  0.333456  0.886134
4  0.086916  0.090911  0.557082      4  0.860656  0.165118  0.230746
5  0.856184  0.884198  0.636849      5  0.052435  0.858721  0.339225
6  0.955805  0.151886  0.221581      6  0.393247  0.270365  0.123228
7  0.332495  0.256805  0.312205      7  0.456939  0.234717  0.563153
8  0.118446  0.375340  0.029774      8  0.202765  0.511387  0.948326
9  0.537782  0.945828  0.445125      9  0.371834  0.954219  0.057206
```

Answer (score 0):

Panda now provides a to_html() method.

You can use it like:

`df.to_html()`

Here the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)